# Same CA signed certificate for both salesforce act as server (Mutual TLS) and salesforce act as client

Tags: rest-api, authentication, certificates, authorization, api-client-certificate

Can i use same CA signed certificate for both salesforce act as server (Mutual TLS) and salesforce act as client(2 way ssl).

Actually in one of my project we have exposed some api to external system and consuming some apis hosted on the same external system.

So, just wanted to know that if we can use the same certificate as inbound connect for mutual tls and store this in mutual tls certificate table and also store the same in generic certificate list for client authentication to external server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there should be two different certificate one for mutual tls where salesforce is acting as server and second for two way ssl where salesforce is acting as client to callout third party webservices.

Thanks,

Dildar Hussain